# vagrant-omnibus: not a valid version of chef

Tags: vagrant, chef

At some point I started receiving following error while trying to provision new vm with vagrant:

> There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix the
>   following errors and try again:
>
> vagrant-omnibus:
>   * '11.16' is not a valid version of Chef.
>
> A list of valid versions can be found at:
>   http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/

The same thing happens when I try different versions, like "11", "12" and so on. What is interesting, trying to fetch metadata manually fails with error:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ wget https://www.getchef.com/chef/metadatav=11.16.2&prerelease=false&nightlies=false&p=ubuntu&pv=14.04&m=x86_64
[1] 1555
[2] 1556
[3] 1557
[4] 1558
[5] 1559
vagrant@precise64:~$ --2014-12-15 20:10:29--  https://www.getchef.com/chef/metadata?v=11.16.2 Resolving www.getchef.com (www.getchef.com)... 184.106.28.82 Connecting to www.getchef.com (www.getchef.com)|184.106.28.82|:443... connected. ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches
        requested host name `www.getchef.com'. To connect to www.getchef.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

May this be the reason why omnibus cannot find chef package? How do I solve this problem anyway?

Answer (score 0):

While you didn't include much on the actual error, the issue with wget is because you are missing a `?` and not quoting the URL. For the original and real error, there is a chance that the script is failing to auto-detect your OS or platform correctly. What OS is this on?

Comment: Obviously issue with `wget` was not connected to quoting or something like this. I don't have link right now, but it is a know bug of wget which was fixed in later versions but I don't have possibility to update. The reason for original is still not know. On windows in cygwin it appears but in cmd it not.

Comment: You are incorrect, those "[1] 1555" lines are because bash was running background commands. The unquoted `&`s are both a statement separator and run the command in the background, even if the command is just `prerelease=false`.

Comment: Oh, now I see. Yes, you are right, sorry. `&` made commands to run in background. But, unfortunately, even with quoted url, it not works because of that bug :(

Comment: The correct command (and URL) is `curl -L 'https://www.getchef.com/chef/metadata?v=11.16.2&prerelease=false&nightlies=false&p=ubuntu&pv=14.04&m=x86_64'` and works fine.